# Clean HTTP Requests in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, httprequest

I'am using the Intellij HTTP-Client.

After each Request, the Server-Response is stored in the .idea/httpRequests folder. In my Folder are many json-Files now.

How is it posible to clean this Fodler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exploring-http-syntax.html#enable-disable-saving-request):

**Disable saving requests to requests history**

If necessary, you can prevent saving a request to the requests history. This can be helpful in case a request contains some sensitive data, and you don't want to log it.

Before the request, add a comment line with the `@no-log` tag.

```
// @no-log
GET example.com/api
```

As for cleaning the folder, you can select all the files and delete them as usual.